# How can I retrieve object keys from a sequence in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker, ofbiz

I have a list of objects that are returned as a sequence, I would like to retrieve the keys of each object so as to be able to display the object correctly. At the moment I try **data?first?keys** which seems to get something like the queries that return the objects (Not sure how to explain that last sentence either but img below shows what I'm trying to explain).
[image]

The objects amount of objects returned are correct (7) but displaying the keys for each object is my aim. The [macro that attempts this is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650949/whats-the-meaning-of-within-a-variable-expression-in-freemarker) (from the apache ofbiz development book chapter 8).

Comment: is `data?first?keys` a hash object?

Comment: don't know. Possibly. Possible for a sequence to be composed of a list of hash objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it my sequence is a list of hashes and as explained by Daniel Dekany [this post](http://freemarker.624813.n4.nabble.com/Can-t-get-hashes-to-work-td626670.html):

> The original problem is that, someHash[key] expects a 
>   *string* as key. Because, the hash type of FTL, by definition, maps 
>   *string* keys to arbitrary values. It's not the same as Java's Map. 
>   (Note that to further complicate the matters, in FTL 
>   someSequenceOrString[index] expects an integer index. So, the [] thing 
>   is used for that too.) Now someBeanWrappedMap(key) has technically 
>   nothing to do with all the []-s, it's just a method call, so it 
>   accepts all kind of keys. If you have a Map with non-string keys, you 
>   must use that.

Thanks D Dekany if you're on stack, this ended my half day frustration with the ftl template.

Comment: Note that starting from 2.3.22 there's `?api` for the rescue. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28794648/606679), or [this FAQ entry](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_nonstring_keys) for details.